# How the program is accessing the variables of structures?

Tags: c, struct

I am solving some of the problems related to Structures in C Programming and encountered the following code snippet, whose output is being asked:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>

struct ournode {
    char x,y,z;
};

int main(void) {
    struct ournode p = {'1','0','a'+2};
    struct ournode *q = &p;
    fprintf(stdout,"%c %c\n", *((char*)q+1),*((char*)q+2));
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand how the `fprintf("%c %c", *((char*)q+1),*((char*)q+2))` is accesing the structure `struct ournode` variables.

What can be benefits of accessing the variables like this rather I can do the same with the following code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>

struct ournode {
    char x,y,z;
};

int main(void) {
    struct ournode p = {'1','0','a'+2};
    struct ournode *q = &p;
    fprintf(stdout,"%c %c\n", (q->y),(q->z));
    return 0;
}
```

`Answer/Ouput : 0,c`

Comment: There's no benefit to doing that. It's not safe, and there's no reason to do it. The only reason I could see someone trying to do it is for some sort of polymorphic code, but this is not the right way to do this.

Comment: There is no benefit. Moreover the result might be unexpected if there is padding between the members.

Comment: The only benefit I see to this construct from hell is that you know a code review with your superior is coming and you're looking for a way to get conveniently fired.

Comment: A benefit can be teaching that a structure is not something transcendental, but it is saved in memory just like the other data types.

Answer (score 0):

Their code is absurd. There is only 1 good reason I could think of doing what they did, and that is for backwards compatibility with really old systems. The early versions of C did not allow for the -> arrow operator to be used for dereferencing pointers. However, if they are trying to abide to the 1970s standard, something is wrong with them.

I think the person you are refrencing doesn't understand the arrow operator.

Answer (score -1):

> I am not able to understand

`(char*)q+1` [casts](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting) the pointer `q` to a `char` pointer, so that the underlying memory of the `ournode` is viewed as a sequence of `char`s; then `q+1` points to the next `char` after the beginning of that memory chunk, which is the `'1'`.

> What can be benefits of accessing the variables like this

For a toy example like this, it is not beneficial. For real-world examples, it is usually still a work-around a bad design, but sometimes still useful. It's a way to treat the same chunk of memory as having multiple different structures, without declaring it ahead of time (e.g. using `union`s). Normally, however, you should not do this; it is not safe and does not realistically offer benefits vs. code that was properly designed from the ground up.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, struct padding may mean that the memory layout of a struct is not what you naively expect, making this sort of technique not work the way you expect it to. If you don't already understand it then it is not worth bothering with :)

Comment: Is it a good practice to typecast a structure pointer to a datatype pointer which is same as the datatype of the variable whose value is being extracted. For E.g. Here the code is casting the structure pointer to a char pointer in order to extract the data from the char variable.